# Cannot read bz2 compressed file in hadoop job

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I have an XML file to be processed in a MapReduce job. While I can process it when it is uncompressed, it does not work when I compress it to bz2 format and store it in hdfs. Do I need to make some changes like specify what codec to use - I don't know where to do that. Any example would be great. I am using XMLInputFormat from mahaout to read the uncompressed XML file. I used `bzip2` command to compress the file and `hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal` to copy the file to DFS. I am interested in reading and processing content inside `<page></page>` tag of the xml document. I am using hadoop-1.2.1 distribution. I can see there is `FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass`, but there isn't anything similar for FileInputFormat.

Here is the `Main` class of my job.

```
    public class Main extends Configured implements Tool {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Main(), args);
            System.exit(res);
        }

        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

            if (args.length != 2) {
                System.err.println("Usage: hadoop jar XMLReaderMapRed "
                        + " [generic options] <in> <out>");
                System.out.println();
                ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
                return 1;
            }

            Job job = new Job(getConf(), "XMLTest");

            job.setInputFormatClass(MyXMLInputFormat.class);
            //Specify the start and end tag that has content
            getConf().set(MyXMLInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, "<page>");
            getConf().set(MyXMLInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, "</page>");

            job.setJarByClass(getClass());
            job.setMapperClass(XMLReaderMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(XmlReaderReducer.class);

            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

            boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
            return success ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Reading from Hadoop - The Definitive Guide by Tom White, it is mentioned that "if your input files are compressed, they will be decompressed automatically as they are read by mapReduce, using the filename extension to determine which codec to use." So the file is decompressed automatically, but then why there is empty file created in output directory ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should look at your **core-site.xml** configuration file and add a class for BZip2 codec if it's absent.
Here is an example:

```
<property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
```

Edit:

After adding codec please reproduce next steps to see that it works (your code may not):

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp/wordcount/
echo "three one three three seven" >> /tmp/words
bzip2 -z /tmp/words
hadoop fs -put /tmp/words.bz2 /tmp/wordcount/
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples.jar wordcount /tmp/wordcount/ /tmp/wordcount_out/
hadoop fs -text /tmp/wordcount_out/part*
#you should see next three lines:
one     1
seven   1
three   3
#clean up
#this commands may be different in your case
hadoop fs -rmr /tmp/wordcount_out/
hadoop fs -rmr /tmp/wordcount/
```

Comment: There was no change. I added codec as told - lzo wasn't on my machine so removed them. Still I get an empty file after the job has finished. Please let me know I should produce some more information.

Comment: I guess, there is something wrong with your job not the configuration.
Please run wordcount example with bz2 file as input and tell me what happens.
The command should be something like:
    **hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-examples.jar wordcount /tmp/wordcount/ /tmp/wordcount_out/**

And check output with 'hadoop fs' util:
 **hadoop fs -text /tmp/wordcount_out/part***

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I added the exact steps to check that bz2 codec works.

Comment: I had checked this with the wordcount job that come packaged with hadoop. It works and gives the correct output. I use [XMLInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/ad84344e4055b1e6adff5779339a33fa29e1265d/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes/XmlInputFormat.java) to read data from XML file. This works well when file is not compressed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TextInputFormat` implementation you're probably overriding `createRecordReader` and returning a custom implementation of `RecordReader<KEYIN, VALUEIN>` that doesn't take the codec into account. The default implementation returns a `LineRecordReader` that handles codecs correctly. You can find a reference implementation [here](https://github.com/goiri/Cloud9/blob/29971042f6ea51509ccfda21bef624184f343493/src/dist/edu/umd/cloud9/collection/XMLInputFormat.java), and the relevant changes required [here](https://github.com/lintool/Cloud9/pull/54/commits/29971042f6ea51509ccfda21bef624184f343493).